# Show that $P_{n+1}(x)=x^2\left(P_n(x)-\frac{d}{dx}P_n(x)\right).$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Question: Consider the function $f(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{t}}, t>0$. Let for each positive integer $n$, $P_n$ be the polynomial such that $\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t)=P_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{t}}, \forall t>0$. Show that $$P_{n+1}(x)=x^2\left(P_n(x)-\frac{d}{dx}P_n(x)\right).$$

My solution: It is given that $$f(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{t}}, \forall t>0.$$ Also it is given that $$\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t)=P_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)e^{-\frac{1}{t}}, \forall t>0, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$$ $$\implies \frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t)=P_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)f(t), \forall t>0, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Now $$f'(t)=e^{-\frac{1}{t}}t^{-2}=t^{-2}f(t), \forall t>0.$$

Therefore for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and any $t>0$, we have $$\frac{d^{n+1}}{dt^{n+1}}f(t)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{d^n}{dt^n}f(t)\right)=\frac{d}{dt}\left(P_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)f(t)\right)\\=f(t)P_n'\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\left(-\frac{1}{t^2}\right)+P_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)f'(t)$$ $$=f(t)P_n'\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\left(-t^{-2}\right)+P_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)t^{-2}f(t)\\=f(t)\left\{t^{-2}\left(P_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-P_n'\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right)\right\}$$ $$=P_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)f(t).$$

This implies that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and any $t>0$ $$P_{n+1}\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)=t^{-2}\left(P_n\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)-P_n'\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\right).$$

Now setting $x=t^{-1}$ in the equality obtained above, we can conclude that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we have, $$P_{n+1}(x)=x^2\left(P_n(x)-\frac{d}{dx}P_n(x)\right).$$

Can someone check if my solution is correct or not, and if possible, provide a more better solution. And does the polynomial $P_n$ has some special name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP's proposition and its proof is fully  correct. Note
if
$$P_n(1/t)=e^{1/t}~\frac{d^n e^{-1/t}}{dt^n}$$
then
$$P_{n+1}(x)=x^2[P_n(x)-P'_n(x)] ~~~~(1)$$
An un-initiated reader may verify (1) using $P_1(x)=x^2, P_2(x)= x^4-2x^3, P_3(x)=x^6-6x^5+6x^4$.
Moreover, I have verified that OP's proof is fully  correct.